# Storyboard not loading GUI but still compiling

Tags: ios, xcode

I am building an application and just switched the computer the files were originally housed on.  Now the app will still build and it looks exactly as it should, but the storyboard in xCode is full of a bunch of blank views.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably designed your storyboard in a specific *size class*. Thus, all those views are *conditional* for that size class. Now, however, you've opened the project on a different computer, and the storyboard is showing the universal `w:Any h:Any` setting. Thus, all those views are missing. The app still works, though, because when it runs, the app is *in* the size class environment for which you designed it, and so the views appear.

To see the views in the storyboard, switch the storyboard to whatever that specific size class is.